# While databinding checkboxlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have two checkbox lists in asp.net,

1st list has all fruit names and 2nd list has only few fruit names.

list are getting populated from database using sqldatasource

**now I need to do something so that 1st list with all fruits should only have fruits that are not in list 2**

Here's the code sir,

```
private void AllFruitsNames()
{
    using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), "SELECT FruitName FROM FruitTable"))
    {
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
            CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "FruitName";
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
    }
}

private void PopulateOnlyFewFruitsNames(int crateID)
{
    CheckBoxList2.Items.Clear();

    using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(CS(), "SELECT FruitName FROM FruitTable Where crateID ='" + crateID + "'"))
    {
            CheckBoxList2.DataSource = ds;
            CheckBoxList2.DataTextField = "FruitName";
            CheckBoxList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

How can I balance fruits as if a fruit is in 2nd checkbox list then it should be removed from checkboxlist 1

Comment: Where does crateID come from?

Comment: from drop down list, sir , index changed event i am using

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have the IDs of the fruits you want to be in the 2nd list.

Just exclude all fruits with this ids from the first query:

```
"SELECT FruitName FROM FruitTable WHERE crateID NOT IN(" + String.Joing(",",crateIDList) + ")"
```

BTW: You really **should not** build SQL queries this way. They are vulnerable to sql injection. Use parameterized queries instead. Here is an article on the topic: [Using parameterized queries with the SQLDataSource](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)